# CSS HTML Table background color overflowing

Tags: html, css, background, html-table, space

I have been trying to make a Table based navigation bar made of 5 side by side images that, when hovered and clicked, "highlight" using reduced opacity on :active and :hover with a light background color. For example

```
    .navbright {
background-color:#FFC39A;
}
.navbright:hover {
opacity: 0.6;
}

.navbright:active {
opacity: 0.3;
}
```

The problem is the implementation of the background color. It is always sitting lower than the image by a few pixels. All the solutions I've researched have not worked, i.e. border-collapse:collapse; margin-bottom:-3px; setting all borders padding spacing margins to 0 etc etc.

I would like to find a Table solution based around eliminating the extra space/ background space. If this is not possible, perhaps someone can tell me how to construct the same construct using strictly CSS instead of a table.

The one case where I got it to "work" is when I used divs, and set the background-color as part of the div's class i.e.:

```
    <td><div class="navbright"><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="/images/Home.jpg" alt="" width="200"></a></div></td>
```

However, with this solution there was an annoying extra line appearing during the :active phase, which is unresolved here: [CSS HTML line appearing on div :active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469114/css-html-line-appearing-on-div-active) not to mention the fact that the background image ceased working...

So I set out to solve it using table bgcolor. I cannot get rid of the extra background color showing up beneathe the table no matter what I do. I am exhausted, and need expert help. Here's the table coding:

```
    <table id="page" align="center" width="1000" height="37">
<tr>
  <td><a class="navbright" href="http://www.criticalawakening.com"><img src="/images/Home.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
  <td><a class="navbright" href="http://www.criticalawakening.com/Articles.html"><img src="/images/Articles.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
  <td><a class="navbright" href="http://www.criticalawakening.com/Forum.html"><img src="/images/Forum.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
  <td><a class="navbright" href="http://www.criticalawakening.com/Store.html"><img src="/images/Store.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
  <td><a class="navbright" href="http://www.criticalawakening.com/Contact.html"><img src="/images/Contact.jpg" alt=""><a></a></td>
</tr>
```

with #page basically being an attempt to collapse the extra space

```
    #page td {
  padding:0; margin:0;
}

#page {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. And also, if someone has a good idea for a CSS only design without tables to achieve the same thing please let me know. Basically, its a 1000px wide centered column.

Comment: Can u provide the jsfiddle snippet ?

Comment: Okay I couldn't even get the fiddle script to bunch the images side by side but the idea is the lower example without all the extra background, sitting right beneathe the blue banner: http://jsfiddle.net/4jx5te1z/3/

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that was a ton of work. I found *a* solution, perhaps not *THE* best solution.

First, I set the TABLE to house the background color, and displayed it as a BLOCK...

```
    <table style="display:block;position:relative;top:0px;" align="center" height="37" width="1000" bgcolor="#FFC39A" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

I decided to approach it with a simple inline-series of images. I set the IMAGE as the .navbar class, and changed its rules as following:

```
.navbright {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
}
```

Taking away the whole background task from the class entirely. Setting the positions to relative allowed much more flexibility with the positioning, even though they are both modified by 0px... go figure...

There is still one last glitch of a border showing upon :active around my links but that is another question... [CSS HTML line appearing on div :active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469114/css-html-line-appearing-on-div-active)